# Symfony2 : Session upload progress

Tags: php, symfony, session, upload

I'm trying to use the php upload_progress feature with symfony2. I set my session.upload_progress.prefix and session.upload_progress.name in my php.ini.
My form below :

```
<form id="form-import-file" action="" method="post" {{    form_enctype(form) }} class="form-horizontal">                                    
    {{ form_widget(form.file, { 'attr':{'class':'input-file-import'}}) }}
    {{ form_rest(form) }}     
    {{ form_errors(form.file) }}
    <input type="hidden" name="{{ upload_progress_name }}" value="123" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>
```

where upload_progress_name = ini_get("session.upload_progress.name").

The upload is okay, but the session doesn't show any upload infos.
Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that `<input type="hidden" name="{{ upload_progress_name }}" value="123" />`
is before the file input fields. Just place it under the form tag.
Also what helped me out is this list: [issues on php upload progress](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21851657/3060626)

Finally there is good symfony2-bundle, which may help you to not reinvent everything new.[OneUpBundle](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle)
With this bundle you can pick a Frontend solution or create your own one.