# session.upload_progress.enabled doesn't work

Tags: php, ajax, session

**SOLVED**

I want to create a progress bar for uploading a file in my site.
I read about `session.upload_progress.enabled` and I tried to use this
This is my php.ini:

```
session.upload_progress.enabled = On  
session.upload_progress.cleanup = On  
session.upload_progress.prefix = "upload_progress_"  
session.upload_progress.name = "video"  
session.upload_progress.freq =  "1%"  
session.upload_progress.min_freq = "1"
```

Then, I put this in my form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="video" value="video" />
```

And I did an ajax request to the php file to get the information , since it didn't work I tried to debug and I put in the php file:

```
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
```

And all I get from this page is:

```
 Array
 (
 )
```

So, I searched for this problem and I got to this Answer: [PhP Upload progress in PhP 5.4 is not working. Session variables not set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21703081/php-upload-progress-in-php-5-4-is-not-working-session-variables-not-set)

1) I have php version:5.6.8
2) The SESSION is initialized as you can see in my code
3) I don't run fastCGI I run php with xampp on windows

What is the problem and how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Do not put name="video" in your input file.
I searched the php manual (http://php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php)

It says put 
`name="<?php echo ini_get("session.upload_progress.name"); ?>"
<input type="file" name="file1" />
<input type="file" name="file2" /> 
and then put <input type="submit" />`

and it should be put in the exact same order as above.